# Shortcode is not showing content when placed in editor (post_type = page)

Tags: shortcode, post-type

I have created a `shortcode`, which I want to use in pages. When I place this shortcode in a page (`post_type = 'page'`), it does now display the content. But if I place the same shortcode in a post (`post_type = 'post'`), it displays the content.

Is there any special adjustment to be made in the shortcode so that I can use it on pages as well?

```
function mbs_shortcode_content() {
   ob_start(); ?>
   <div>Shortcode content to be added here...</div>
   <?php return ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'init', function(){
   add_shortcode( 'mbs-clients', 'mbs_shortcode_content' );
} );
```

I tried by breaking down the above code block as well like this:

```
function register_client_shortcode() {
   add_shortcode( 'mbs-clients', 'mbs_shortcode_content' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_client_shortcode' );
```

When used in post type `post`, content is visible, but nothing is showing up when used in post type `page`.

**FULL CODE**

The following code is placed in `plugin.php` at the root of my plugin folder.

```
function mbs_client_list_shortcode() {

    ob_start();

    $us_clients = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'   => 'mbs-clients',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => '_mbs_clients_zone',
                    'value'   => 'USA',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'orderby' => '_mbs_clients_state',
                    'order'   => 'ASC'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $int_clients = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type'   => 'mbs-clients',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => '_mbs_clients_zone',
                    'value'   => 'INT',
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        )
    ); ?>

    <div style="display:block;">

        <?php if( $us_clients->have_posts() ) {
            while($us_clients->have_posts()) {
                $us_clients->the_post();
                $addr = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_clients_short_address', true );
                $lat  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_clients_lat', true );
                $lng  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_clients_lng', true );
                echo $addr;
                ?>

                <input type="text" class="list" value="<?php echo $addr; ?>|<?php echo $lat; ?>|<?php echo $lng; ?>" />
            <?php }
        } ?>
    </div>

    <div style="display:block;">
        <?php if( $int_clients->have_posts() ) {
            while($int_clients->have_posts()) {
                $int_clients->the_post();
                $addr = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_clients_short_address', true );
                $lat  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_clients_lat', true );
                $lng  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_clients_lng', true );
                echo $addr;
                ?>
                <input type="text" class="list" value="<?php echo $addr; ?>|<?php echo $lat; ?>|<?php echo $lng; ?>" />
            <?php }
        } ?>
    </div>

    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}

function register_mbs_shortcode() {
    add_shortcode( 'mbs-client-list', 'mbs_client_list_shortcode' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_mbs_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Can you place full code here? What you are adding in the shortcode content?

Comment: +1 to adding full code, even if you don't think it's relevant or important please edit your question to include the full code for your shortcode, at the moment it's not clear what the shortcode does. Also how are you adding/using the shortcode? I assume by not showing you mean on the frontend? Does it show nothing? Does it show the shortcode unprocessed? It's not clear what "not showing" means, also where is this code? Is it in a plugin? `functions.php`? Answer all the Q's as best you can, even if the answer is that you aren't sure

Comment: I have updated my original question with full code.

Comment: A sidenote, your `_mbs_clients_zone` post meta should be a taxonomy, it would give huge performance gains and make querying simpler, as well as giving you a free post archive for each client zone and theme template options and URLs

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell. I will modify that for sure. Did you get anything wrong in the shortcode by the way? If yes, please let me know. I need to place it in the editor of `page` post_type.

Comment: imo it didn't show anything because it didn't find anything, and you have no `} else { echo "nothing was found"; }` in your code, so it looks the same when it finds nothing as it would if it was just broken. As for why your queries find no posts, I'm not sure at the moment

Comment: The same query does work on a `post`, but not `page`. That's my concern! Can you enlighten me on this please?